# How do I vertically center text in a DIV using CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble center text vertically in a DIV using CSS. I've followed the related answers here on SO and elsewhere, but can't seem to get it to work. My simplified scenario is

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="header-title">
        <span class="header-text">This is the title</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
div.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;

}

div.header-title {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 100%; /* required */
    color: green;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width:1px;
}

span.header-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

but the result (in Safari) leaves the 'header-text' `span` at the top of the 'header-title' `div`:

[image]

Comment: Your example is centered. What's wrong?

Comment: Ur fiddle is working fine... what are you looking for??

Comment: @Morpheus: Hmmm. Could it be my browser then? I'll post an image of hat I see in Safari.

Comment: You have posted the fiddle with different code. Here it is with your provided HTML and CSS http://jsfiddle.net/D4quh/315/

Comment: @Morpheus: Yes, sorry; my mistake. My first fiddle and I got the link wrong (and lost mine). That's the answer: I was missing `display: table;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example shows a good workaround for vertically centering elements in a div:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

so add it to your div css:

```
div.header-title {
position: absolute;
font-size: 36px;
height: 100%; /* required */
color: green;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
border-style: dashed;
border-width:1px;
}
```